# Change jQuery to Trigger When the Site Is Loaded Instead on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to modify the following jQuery to trigger when the site is loaded instead on scroll. (This is for a message banner that goes on the top of a site. I want it there all the time, not just when I scroll. ([test.micahbickford.com](http://test.micahbickford.com))

```
    jQuery(function( $ ){
// Add reveal class to utility bar after 50px
    $(document).on("scroll", function(){
        var height = $(".utility-bar")[0].clientHeight;
        if($(document).scrollTop() >= 0){
            $(".site-header.dark").css("top",height+"px");
            $(".utility-bar").addClass("reveal");

        } else {
            $(".site-header.dark").css("top",0+"px");
            $(".utility-bar").removeClass("reveal");
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried changing "scroll" to "load" and "ready" but that just makes the banner disappear altogether.

Comment: Just remove the `scroll` handler completely

Comment: Sounds like all you need is to adjust your css rules and don't need any script for it

Answer (score 0):

The first event handler that you wrote

```
jQuery(function () {
  // code here
})
```

is just a shortcut for the more verbose "ready" event handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // code here
})
```

This event handler is executed when the DOM is fully loaded.

In your example, if you only want the code to be executed at the loading of the page instead of on scrolling, you simply need to remove the scroll event handler

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
    // Add reveal class to utility bar after 50px
    var height = $(".utility-bar")[0].clientHeight;
    if($(document).scrollTop() >= 50){
        $(".site-header.dark").css("top",height+"px");
        $(".utility-bar").addClass("reveal");

    } else {
        $(".site-header.dark").css("top",0+"px");
        $(".utility-bar").removeClass("reveal");
    }
});
```

*I did change the condition of your if () to be higher or equal than 50 instead of 0. I think it makes more sense like that.*

But, in this case, the script loses the ability to add the *reveal* CSS class to the utility bar after 50px when we scroll.

Maybe what you really want is to keep the scroll event handler, but ensure that the code inside it is executed at the page loading too. There are many ways to do that, but in this case, we can keep the scroll event handler and trigger a scroll event after the scroll event handler binding.

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
    // Add reveal class to utility bar after 50px
    $(document).on("scroll", function(){
        var height = $(".utility-bar")[0].clientHeight;
        if($(document).scrollTop() >= 50){
            $(".site-header.dark").css("top",height+"px");
            $(".utility-bar").addClass("reveal");
        } else {
            $(".site-header.dark").css("top",0+"px");
            $(".utility-bar").removeClass("reveal");
        }
    });

    $(document).trigger('scroll');
});
```

On a final note, if what you really want is to keep your banner identical and always at the top of the viewport, this script can be replaced by some fairly simple CSS looking like

```
.utility-bar { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; }
```